# Semantics of ib_buffer_pool file in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

MySQL's default storage engine, InnoDB, maintains an internal buffer pool of database pages. In newer versions of MySQL (e.g. 5.7+) the space and page IDs of the pages in the buffer pool are persisted to disk in the "ib_buffer_pool" file.

I'm curious about how this file is constructed, and **in particular if the relative young-ness/old-ness of the pages in the buffer pool persists across restarts.** In other words, if some page in the pool is younger than some other page, will that relationship hold after the file is written to, and then read from, the disk?

A broader question is the following: **how much of the state of the InnoDB buffer pool persists across restarts?**

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you ask does not matter.

That file contains pointers, not data blocks.  Each "pointer" probably contain the tablespace id (ibdata1 versus individual .ibd files) and block number.  It would be handy, but not absolutely necessary to include the LRU info.

The goal is to quickly refill the RAM-based "buffer pool" after a restart.  The buffer pool is a *cache*; in the past is was simply not reloaded.  During normal activity, the blocks in the buffer pool are organized based (somewhat) on "least recently used".  This helps prevent bumping out a block "too soon".

If all the block *pointers* are stored in that file before shutting down, then the buffer pool can be restored to essentially where it was.  At restart, this takes some disk activity, but after that, each query should be as fast as if the restart had not occurred..

If, because of whatever, some block is inappropriately reloaded, it will be a minor performance hit, but nothing will be "wrong".  That block will soon be bumped out of the buffer pool.

How much state persists across a restart?  Well, the absolute requirement is that the integrity of the data in the database be maintained -- even across a power failure.  Anything beyond that is just performance optimizations.  So, to fully answer the question, one needs to understand iblog* (needed after a crash; not needed after clean shutdown), the new tmp table file (not needed), the "double buffer" (used to recover from 'torn page' after abrupt crash), etc.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I understand that it *probably* doesn't matter for normal purposes if the buffer pool file is written in some kind of LRU order, but for my current project (related to database forensics) I need to know what the current behavior is.